# What is the meaning of "have" in the sentence "I have some hobbies"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

See this sentence "**I have some hobbies**".

In [the dictionary](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/have_1?q=have), the word "**have**" has many meanings. One of its meanings is

> **have something**: to experience something
>
> *I went to a few parties and had a good time.*
>
> *I was having difficulty in staying awake.*
>
> *She'll have an accident one day.*

Does "**have**" in the sentence "*I have some hobbies*" mean "**to experience something**".

It is important because we can use continuous tenses with this meaning.

Eg, **I am having a good time**

Note: if "**have**" means own, then we can not use "continuous tenses" in this case.

Eg: It is wrong to say: **I am having a car**.

Can we say "***I am having some hobbies***"?

Comment: [***I am having** a question about Indian English. Why **are we wanting** to talk in the present continuous tense all the time?*](http://blogs.intoday.in/businesstoday/Indianism-of-the-Week-37---continuous-tense-62749.html) In short, you might be able to say *I am having some hobbies* in Indian English, but it will be noticed and considered an error by all "mainstream" Anglophones.

Comment: You might find [this discussion about **I'm loving it**](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/im-lovin-it-loving.26862/) interesting. As some examples there show, the continuous isn't *always* incorrect in such constructions. But it's at least *slightly* unusual, which I'm sure would have been part of the reason for featuring it in McDonald's ad campaigns (to catch people's attention, not to make it sound "Indian").

Comment: Compare "I have a hobby" to "I have a job". Your dictionary seems to consider this an example of the "own or posses" meaning of *to have*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, when you have a job, don't you usually mean that you have had it for some time and expect to keep it for some time in the future? The Indian usage seems to be more consistent with other uses of present continuous than the American and British idiomatic usage.

Comment: I guess the difference is that *to have* already conveys an ongoing state without having to be put in a continuous tense.

Comment: @The Photon: To be sure. In fact there are a number of situations where it's easy to defend an IE usage as more *logical* than mainstream English. But that's largely because there are relatively few *native* Anglophones in India. So Indians are more likely to (a) retain antiquated usages that they find in older written texts, and (b) gravitate towards the more "logical" versions where they hear a variety of different usages. They don't tend to hear current mainstream usages so often, so don't always change *their* usages in tandem with how language evolves among actual native speakers.

Comment: You can have a good time or a bad time.  

You can have second thoughts.  

You can have an idea. 

You can have a stomach flu. 

You can have a bowel movement.

You can have a job or an avocation. 

You can have a friend.  

You can have soup for lunch. 

You can have a blister on your heel.

You can have 20/20 vision.

You can have sex.  You can have enough.  You can have too little. You can have nothing.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I would be careful about generalizations re English in India. Those who have been schooled in English do not tend to use the continuous as much. Here, with  hobby, unless one is wanting to use that variety of English, marked as Indian, one wouldn't use it.

Comment: @Lambie: I'm not sure if your *unless one **is wanting** to use that variety of English* there was a joke or not! I think that's a typical context where IE speakers would consider the continuous to be "logical", even though *mainstream* Anglophones simply wouldn't use it.

Comment: [*...the peculiarities of Indian usages can be attributed to three different sources: the **older usage of British English, which has now disappeared from native English but retained in Indian English;** the influence of Indian mother tongues...*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+peculiarities+of+indian+usages%22)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, it was a joke. You have seen enough of my English to realize that.

Answer (score 1):

No, one does not experience a hobby.

I think the relevant definition for *have a hobby* is either

> 1. to own, hold or possess something

or possibly

> 5. used to show a particular relationship

although that's a bit of a stretch. In my experience, a hobby is often thought of as something that one possesses. Do keep in mind that possession is not necessarily exclusive.

Indeed, one of the examples under definition 1 is *Have you got a job yet?*, which is very closely analogous. As was mentioned in the comments, one can talk about having a job in the same sense as having a hobby.